# Web Api in MVC4 project cannot Access API Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have an MVC4 project with many controllers. I added an API controller called `BatchDetailsController` in the root directory of the project.

I also created a `WebApiConfig` class as below:

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

I also invoke the above register method from global.asax as

```
  WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

in `Application_Start`

Now I have tried to access the controller by using then URLs
/BatchDetails
/api/BatchDetails
/BatchDetails/Get
/api/BatchDetails/Get

All of them return 404

What is the URL I need to use in this case?

Answer (score 0):

for example when using visual studio to debug/host the project the url would be http://localhost:port/api/BatchDetals/{method}

Right click on the project and see if IIS express is selected and note the port number. The project should come up via run/f5 in visual studio at the Project URL.

If not I would re-install IIS8 express.

[image: Visual Studio Project Settings]

Comment: where is the project hosted (visual studio cassini?) IIS express other?

Comment: Add HttpGet attribute on BatchDetails method and try 
localhost:50130/api/BatchDetails

Comment: See related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16944947/mvc-attribute-routing-not-working