# With attribute routing enabled, and no default routing, why is my API still returning on the old default route?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Note: I'm new to C#, asp.net, and all the things that go along with it.

I've created a class called `Review.cs` with some attributes.

I also have a controller called `ReviewController.cs`. The idea behind this controller is that I should be able to have three different components:

1) `GET` all reviews
2) `GET` all reviews where `siteID` = a parameter
3) `GET` one review

Originally, it was working when I would go to http://localhost:#####/api/Review to find all the reviews, and it also worked when I appended a parameter.

Someone on another question I asked recommended I read up on [Attribute Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2), which I did at the link.

As a result of my reading, my WebApiConfig.cs file now looks like this:

using System.Web.Http;

```
namespace Test_Site_1
{
    public class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            //attribute routing
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        }
    }
}
```

My `ReviewController.cs` file looks like this:

```
namespace Test_Site_1.Controllers
{
    public class ReviewController : ApiController
    {
        private ReviewAPIModel db = new ReviewAPIModel();

        [Route("api/Review/all")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Review> Review()
        {
            return db.Review;
        }

        [Route("api/Review/{siteID}/Reviews")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Review> FindReviewBySite(int siteID)
        {
            return db.Review.Where(Review => Review.siteID == siteID);
        }

        [ResponseType(typeof(Review))]
        [Route("api/Review/single/{id}")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult Review_ByID(int id)
        {
            Review review = db.Review.Find(id);
            if (review == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(review);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, based off of my understanding of the multitude of SO questions and the numerous Microsoft guides I've gone over, the Attribute Routes that I've set up should work as follows:

http://localhost:#####/api/Review 
Expected: should no longer return anything (this is the old default that I removed from `WebApiConfig.cs`).
Actual: returns all reviews

http://localhost:#####/api/Review/all

Expected: should return what used to be returned by the default API above.

Actual: Returns the error `The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult Review_ByID(Int32)'`

http://localhost:#####/api/Review/1/Reviews

Expected: should return all reviews for the site with ID = 1.

Actual: Returns the error `HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`

http://localhost:#####/api/Review/single/1

Expected: should return me the review with ID = 1.

Actual: returns the error `HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`

Where am I going wrong, or what am I missing? It seems like everything should be set up right based off the guides and SO questions I followed.

Comment: It looks like a correct setup. dubblecheck port, rebuild or even try to create new project with same setup and see if its the same output

Comment: Do you mean make sure the port works? When I have a generic .aspx page, the same port info works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this question: [MVC Attribute Routing Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16944947/mvc-attribute-routing-not-working)

It suggested that I need to update my Global.asax.cs file to the following:

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register); 
    }
}
```