# URL with QueryString not hitting MVC Controller method

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, query-string

I've got two methods in a controller. One accepting a parameter, the other one not.

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ClientController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("[action]/{id}")]
    public ObjectResult GetChildNodeObjects(string id)
    {
        //does stuff
    }

    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public ObjectResult GetChildNodeObjects()
    {
        //does other stuff
    }
}
```

Now the problem is the first one, the one accepting a parameter.
When I hit it with `http://localhost:xxxx/api/project/GetChildNodeObjects/231a` it will pick up the parameter just fine. But since I get the URL like this: `http://localhost:xxxx/api/project/GetChildNodeObjects/?id=231a` it goes directly into the other controller method - the one without a parameter. What am I doing wrong for the parameter not to be caught in the second case?

Comment: You need attribute routing - [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16944947/mvc-attribute-routing-not-working/24409709#24409709)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've included a slash. This slash means that the parameterless action kicks in. So simply replace the URL:

```
http://localhost:xxxx/api/project/GetChildNodeObjects/?id=231a
```

With

```
http://localhost:xxxx/api/project/GetChildNodeObjects?id=231a
```

Comment: have you any custom route maps or are they MVC default ones?

Answer (score 0):

You should define in url mappings something like below

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "myrouting",
    "mycontroller/myaction/",
    new { }
    );
```

Comment: Where you define your route, you can enable attribute routing with ' routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();'