# Web API 2 method not found

Tags: c#, webforms, visual-studio-2019, webapi

I have an existing WEB Form(Framework 4.7.2) app to which I added a Web API called  **ClaimController**

I tried to call the webpi using this url /api/claim/Getclaims/2022 but it was not found.

any thing is missing ?

**ClaimController.cs**

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using Dashboard.App_code;

namespace Dashboard.api
{
    public class ClaimController : ApiController
    {    
        
        
        [System.Web.Http.Route("api/Claim/Getclaims/{year?}")]
        [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult Getclaims(string year)
        {
            return Ok(ClData.GetClaimsChart(year));
        }
       
    }
}
```

**Global.asax.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace Dashboard
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` in your `Global.asax.cs` before you define your routes.

Comment: Yes I added that, then I was getting an error , then I added after routing in glabal.asax.cs this instruction GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnsureInitialized();, and now its working, thank you for your help and have a nice time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your setup, you need to add `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()` before your define your routes in `Global.asax.cs` file:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "DefaultApi",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
);

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnsureInitialized();
```

Comment: Please correct: the second line should be after routes definition

Comment: See here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16944947/mvc-attribute-routing-not-working/24409709#24409709